# How to join only one row from one-to-many relation where value is min or max?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

`products`:

```
id|name
1|first
2|second
```

`product_unit`:

```
id|product_id|price
1|1|10
2|1|20
3|2|40
4|2|30
```

I want to select products where min value is greater than 15, and lower than 35. First product min value is 10, for second product min value is 30.

For now I have this query:

```
select products.*, min(product_unit.price) as min_price
from `products`
left join `product_unit`
    on  `product_unit`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
    and (`product_unit`.`value` > '15' and `product_unit`.`value` < '35') 
group by `products`.`id`
```

This query returns:

```
id|name|price
1|first|20
2|second|30
```

But should:

```
id|name|price
2|second|30
```

Because products with id=1 have min price 10 that is lower than 15.

What is the proper query for this?
(I would prefer without derived tables if is possible)

Comment: I'd take a look at the HAVING clause...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it using a derived table.

```
select p.id, p.name, t.minprice as price 
from products p
join (select product_id,min(price) as minprice 
      from product_unit
      group by product_id) t
on t.product_id = p.id
where t.minprice > 15 and t.minprice < 35
```

or

```
select p.id, p.name, t.minprice as price 
from products p
join (select product_id,min(price) as minprice 
      from product_unit
      group by product_id
      having min(price) between 16 and 34) t
on t.product_id = p.id
```

or with out a derived table

```
select pu.product_id,p.name,min(pu.price) as minprice 
from product_unit pu
join products p on pu.product_id = p.id
group by pu.product_id,p.name
having min(pu.price) between 16 and 34
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I think this would work. I would prefer without derived table but maybe is not possible without derived table. Now I need to adapt this for laravel.